# Поля engines и volta в package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Кто может вкратце объяснить что за новые поля (а я их называю новыми, так как год-два назад я их не видел) стали все чаще и чаще (повсеместно) фигурировать в `package.json`:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "18",
    "npm": "9"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.16.0"
  }
```

Желательно своим языком и в кратце. И что за дела, я не устанавливал `volta`, а она есть, глобально

Comment: [engines](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) был всегда, а volta это инструмент коммандной строки по функциям напоминающий nvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле `engines` там было примерно всегда https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#engines

Может использоваться для указания с какой версией NodeJS/NPM работает пакет. См. также поля `os` и `cpu`.

Поле `volta` это «самодеятельность» Volta https://docs.volta.sh/guide/#reproducible-environments-for-collaborators используется для фиксации версии NodeJS для других пользователей Volta.

А вообще, кто угодно может написать в `package.json` почти что угодно. NodeJS и NPM просто игнорируют неизвестные им поля.

Comment: Спасибо, один вопрос только. Я вот точно помню, что не устанавливал себе volta, но теперь он доступен у меня глобально. Там что, происходит попытка установить его глобально в случае, если его нет на компьютере при установке зависимостей? И потом они ноду устанавливают локально?

Comment: @DenisLopatin не верю. Сама volta так точно не умеет. Теоретически в post-install скрипте можно делать что угодно, так что я не удивлюсь если кто-то зачем-то принудительно ставит вольту, но на за такое конечно надо руки обрывать

Comment: Ну так поверьте, не слышал даже о таком инструменте до установки пакета)) А можно подробнее про post-install? или ссылку какую нить? вкратце

Comment: @DenisLopatin https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts